# Unable to read Django FieldFile in custom storage`

Tags: python, django, django-storage

I'm attempting to make a [custom file storage class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-file-storage/) for my Django app that transparently logs a hash of all files saved.

My test storage class is pretty trivial:

```
from django.core.files.storage import Storage
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile

from utils import get_text_hash

class MyStorage(Storage)

    def _save(self, name, content):
        if isinstance(content, FieldFile):
            raw_content = content.open().read()
        else:
            raw_content = content
        assert isinstance(raw_content, basestring)
        print(get_text_hash(raw_content))
        return super(MyStorage, self)._save(name, content)
```

However, when I try and save a file in my app, I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'read'
```

with the traceback ending on the line:

```
raw_content = content.open().read()
```

Why is `open()` returning None instead of a file handle? What's the proper way to access your raw file content inside a Django storage class?

Answer (score 0):

```
raw_content = content.open().read()
```

change to

```
raw_content = content.read()
```

I think you can check these manuals.

[Django Manual _save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-file-storage/#django.core.files.storage._save)

> _save(name, content)¶ Called by Storage.save(). The name will already have gone through get_valid_name() and get_available_name(), and the
>   content will be a File object itself.

So content is File object.

[Django Manual FieldFile.open](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.fields.files.FieldFile.open)

> Opens or reopens the file associated with this instance in the
>   specified mode. Unlike the standard Python open() method, it doesn’t
>   return a file descriptor.